# Want to overwrite my DEV environment with STAGE code ASP.NET Visual Studio 2012 TFS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, tfs

We made a lot of messy mistakes in our DEV branch, and we also upgraded our CMS, which caused even more problems. We would like to overwrite our DEV branch with all the code from our STAGE branch - BUT we would like the branch history to remain in-tact ( be able to see our previous changes to files ).

Is there a way I can do this? We are using TFS.

Comment: Is Dev branched from Stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a complete overwrite, then open up Source Control Explorer and check out the entire branch, then go into your Windows Explorer and delete the entire contents.

Then copy all the files from your Stage Branch to your Dev Branch folder, and check them all in.  TFS will only check in files that have changed, delete files that are not in your stage branch, and add files that were not in your Deb branch.

Alternatively, you can try to merge them down if they are direct descendents, or do a baseless merge.. but that could be a huge pain.

Comment: If you dont need any history from your DEV branch, an alternative would be to delete/destroy the existing DEV branch and create a new branch off your STAGE branch.